# Prometheus metric return delayed date time

Tags: prometheus, grafana, dashboard, promql

Im using this this metric to get date creation of a pod

```
kube_pod_created{pod="consumer-deployment-6588bfd984-ntzdp", namespace="default"}
```

but it returnig the date with delay of an hour prometheus timezone is enabled and when I hover on the graph I can see the correct time as screenshot below shows how can synchronize it ?
[image]